# To select values from the same keys in different objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON file like this;

```
"forecastday": [
  {
    "date": "01-18",
    "day": {
      "maxtempc": 12.6,
      "maxtempf": 54.7,
      "mintempc": 6.1,
      "mintempf": 43.0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Sunny",
        "icon": "a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "01-19",
    "day": {
      "maxtempc": 14.6,
      "maxtempf": 40.3,
      "mintempc": 3.1,
      "mintempf": 41.0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Cloudy",
        "icon": "a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "01-20",
    "day": {
      "maxtempc": 11.1,
      "maxtempf": 50.2,
      "mintempc": 7.2,
      "mintempf": 39.0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Rainy",
        "icon": "a"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I need to select values from maxtempc,maxtempf,mintempc,mintempf,icon from different days and put inside different divs. i am waiting for your helps.

Comment: `i tried map() method but i can't make it work` please show how you tried

Comment: Show what you tried please

Comment: i made a variable ( fcmaxf ) for forecast and i tried to get maxtempf inside of it, i made like that;

`var maxfday = fcmaxf.map(function(d) {
          return d.day.maxtemp_f;
        });` 

i am new on javascript. i need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var days = forecastdayArray.map(i => i.day) // array of day objects with the properties you needed`

```
//accessing the properties
days.forEach(function(item) {
console.log(item.maxtempc)
console.log(item.maxtempf)
console.log(item.mintempc)
console.log(item.mintempf)
console.log(item.condition.icon)
});
```

Comment: i tried this and it gives me the values from first day. how i can get other day's values for append different divs in html ?
http://i64.tinypic.com/34fejih.jpg

Comment: '12.6'
'54.7'
'6.1'
'43'
'a'
'14.6'
'40.3'
'3.1'
'41'
'a'
'11.1'
'50.2'
'7.2'
'39'
'a'

I got this as the output, 
did you use the loop?
can I see your code?

Comment: i used exact same code as yours. i am taking json data from a server and i keep this part of json in a variable like this var forecastdayData = data.forecast.forecastday; inside of getJSON method

Comment: i don't know the difference of the data if it is from the server,
check my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/2xLhrebs/
you might find some solution

Comment: try to console.log(v1) and you'll see that it only has 1 day data,, 
that is why you only get the first day

Comment: in v1, there is a current day data and there is forecast data. in forecast > forcastday, there are 5 days data. i am tring to log in it. i made a variable `var forecastdayData = v1.forecast.forecastday;` and i try log from it not from current day.. you can see in code.

Comment: console.log(forecastdayData) or console.log(v1.forecast.forecastday)  it only outputs 1 object with 1 day, did you send me the wrong codepen link? http://codepen.io/erenesto/pen/zNoMqr
if not, then the problem is with the data fetched from the server

Comment: that is what i say. it outputs 1 object. but in forecastday, there are 5 days. i do not understand why. you can see the json api link in top of JS part.

Comment: ohh, I'm sorry. okay, I will try try to check it

Comment: thank you for your interest. i hope we can find a way.

Comment: i found the problem. i forgot to add days5 variable end of the link variable. now your solution will work i guess

Comment: sorry for yesterday, we had a problem on our site. 
-glad to help:)

Answer (score 1):

```
data.forecastday.map(x => x.day.maxtempc)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i tried this and i look at to log, its just giving first maxtempc from first day. i need loop through add different values to different divs.

Comment: No the map function gives a collection of it. When I run it it gives me the 'maxtempc' from all 3 records

Comment: maybe i should add them in arrays; for example, for maxtempc; `"day" : {"maxtempc" : [12.6, 14.6, 11.1] ` }

Can you help me for this?

Comment: No, this should work, you need to tell us how you are running your code. A sample snippet. You must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to "parse" your json before you can use it...here is a basic way to use your data. I hope this helps.

```
var initialarrays = JSON.parse(`[
  {
    "date": "01-18",
    "day": {
      "maxtempc": 12.6,
      "maxtempf": 54.7,
      "mintempc": 6.1,
      "mintempf": 43.0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Sunny",
        "icon": "a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "01-19",
    "day": {
      "maxtempc": 14.6,
      "maxtempf": 40.3,
      "mintempc": 3.1,
      "mintempf": 41.0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Cloudy",
        "icon": "a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "01-20",
    "day": {
      "maxtempc": 11.1,
      "maxtempf": 50.2,
      "mintempc": 7.2,
      "mintempf": 39.0,
      "condition": {
        "text": "Rainy",
        "icon": "a"
      }
    }
  }
]`);

var mynewarrs = initialarrays.map(function(initialarray){
    return initialarray.day;
})

var finalarrays = mynewarrs.map(function(mynewarr){
  return mynewarr.maxtempc;
});

console.log(mynewarrs);
```

Comment: hello, i am taking json data from a server and i keep this part of json in a variable like this data.forecast.forecastday
how can i parse this ?

Comment: @erenesto JSON.parse will enbale you to deal with the data you recieve from the server as an array.

 you code does a good job, the only problem is that your code must be executed several times in order to get the data he asked for, So why not return a 2D array that contains only the data he asked for ?? just saying

Comment: I best believe Faycal Arab's comment answered it all.

Answer (score 0):

If i really got whaat you are trying to accomplish here's the code you are looking for :

```
var date = initialarrays[i].date;//i refers to index and this is how you extract the date value which correspond to the index you entred.
var maxtempc = initialarrays[i].day.maxtempc;//this line extract the maxtempc value, and this one for the rest of them also;
var icon = initialarrays[i].day.condition.icon;// this one extract the icon value;
```

i hope my examples were clear and if you need to get all of the data you can just loop through initialarrays with a dynamic 'i' and attach each result to its respective div.

that's all and if i missed anything just let me know